# otFoundError: Could not find directory /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Pointing_dogs.zip

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I've been having this problem in my codes which came from a yt vid and I transfer it into google colab cause my device can't do some heavy loads, and this is what my codes looks like

```
import os

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_height = 28
img_width = 28
batch_size = 2
proj_path = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks/Pointing_dogs.zip"
proj_path = pathlib.Path(proj_path)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Input((28, 28, 1)),
        layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding="same"),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(10),
    ]
)

#                      METHOD 1
# ==================================================== #
#             Using dataset_from_directory             #
# ==================================================== #

ds_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    proj_path,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",  # categorical, binary
    # class_names=['0', '1', '2', '3', ...]
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),  # reshape if not in this size
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
)

ds_validation = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_(
    "proj_path",
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",  # categorical, binary
    # class_names=['0', '1', '2', '3', ...]
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),  # reshape if not in this size
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
)


def augment(x, y):
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(x, max_delta=0.05)
    return image, y


ds_train = ds_train.map(augment)

# Custom Loops
for epochs in range(10):
    for x, y in ds_train:
        # train here
        pass


model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=[keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),],
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

model.fit(ds_train, epochs=2, verbose=2)
```

Please tell me what's the solution for this problem

i'm asking for help in my codes, I expect to solve my problem in my codes

Comment: I believe there should be a space in MyDrive, i.e. My Drive. And I would not include `\\` to escape spaces, just do "My Drive"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error, the model is unable to locate the image directory as you have used '/' forward and ' \ ' backward slash both while providing the path to access the folder. You are using a zip file. Please make sure to extract the files from the zip folder for accessing the file and provide the right path to the folder to avoid this error.

After mounting the **Gdrive** with **Google Colab**, you can locate the required folder in the drive and right click to copy the path of the folder using steps below:

[image]